# C++ initialization list in second derrived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, initialization-list

I'm trying to write a relatively deep class heirarchy and my compiler keeps throwing "no matching function for call to [default constructor for bass class]".  Here's the scenario:

```
Class A {
    A(int);//note, no default constructor
}

Class B : public A {
    B(int i, int j) : A(i), someMemberVariable(j) {}
    int someMemberVariable;
}

Class C : public B {
    C(int k, int l) : B(k, l) {}
}
```

and the compiler throws the error on the line for the constructor of class C saying "no matching function for call to A::A()" and tells me to use A::A(int).

I understand that I don't have a default constructor for class A, and the compiler is getting confused when I try to subclass a subclass.  However, what I don't understand is why.  I have used an initialization list to avoid exactly that.  If I only use classes 2-levels deep then it works just fine, but the third class gives me the error.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You should prepare an [`SSCCE`](http://sscce.org). It is hard to believe the above code is representative of your problem, since you did not copy-paste that from any real code (`Class` is not a keyword, semicolons are missing, etc.)

Comment: the constructors should be public; and after fixing the Class, everything compiles on VS2008

Comment: Looks like it works fine here: https://ideone.com/CxoszY .  "my compiler keeps throwing" - Perhaps you would like to share which compiler you're using?

Answer (score 3):

As people commented you just needed to make the constructors public and then your code had some formatting issues:

```
class A 
{
  public:
    A(int a) : blah(a) {}; //note, no default constructor
    int blah;
};

class B : public A 
{
  public:
    B(int i, int j) : A(i), someMemberVariable(j) {}
    int someMemberVariable;
};

class C : public B 
{
  public:
    C(int k, int l) : B(k, l) {}
};

int main( void )
{
  C c(5,4);
  return 0;
}
```

This code compiles cleanly and does what you want.